# Subir proyecto Laravel al Servidor

Tags: php, laravel, hosting

espero estén bien, subí a un hosting un proyecto hecho en laravel, hice todo cuanto dije el tutorial que me proporciono el servicio técnico de la empresa de hosting. Esto es subir todos los archivos y carpetas de mi proyecto al servidor en una carpeta que llame '*laravel*' excepto la carpeta '*public*'. El contenido de public lo subí a la carpeta de '*public_html*' allí modifique el archivo '*index.php*' para que ahora fuera a la carpeta '*laravel*' les muestro...

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

También corregí el archivo .env

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64: Acá va mi key (la borre)
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://jmodontologiaespecializada.com/

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
```

Por ultimo cambie el path de public a public_html en el AppServiceProvider.php

```
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
            return base_path().'/public_html';
        });
    }
```

Esto es todo lo que prácticamente pide el tutorial que se haga para subir a un hosting compartido un proyecto de Laravel, pero aun así no consigo hacerlo andar, al revisar el logs. cada ver que recargo la pagina me tira todos estos errores...

```
[2020-07-28 21:59:17] production.ERROR: View [layouts\jmLayout] not found. (View: /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/resources/views/index.blade.php) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): View [layouts\\jmLayout] not found. (View: /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/resources/views/index.blade.php) at /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:137)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/CompilerEngine.php(41): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->handleViewException(Object(InvalidArgumentException), 1)
#1 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(43): Livewire\\CompilerEngine->handleViewException(Object(InvalidArgumentException), 1)
#2 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/LivewireViewCompilerEngine.php(36): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/home/u16613500...', Array)
#3 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(57): Livewire\\LivewireViewCompilerEngine->evaluatePath('/home/u16613500...', Array)
#4 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(139): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get('/home/u16613500...', Array)
#5 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(122): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
#6 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(91): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
#7 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(62): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
#8 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(34): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->setContent(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#9 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(759): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->__construct(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View), 200, Array)
#10 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(731): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::toResponse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#11 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(685): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#12 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#13 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#14 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#15 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(76): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#16 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#17 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#19 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(62): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Session\\Store), Object(Closure))
#21 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#22 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#24 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(687): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#28 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(662): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(628): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#30 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(617): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(165): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#32 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#34 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#35 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#37 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#39 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(63): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#41 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#43 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#45 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#46 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(140): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#47 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(109): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#48 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/public_html/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#49 {main}

[previous exception] [object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): View [layouts\\jmLayout] not found. at /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:137)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php(79): Illuminate\\View\\FileViewFinder->findInPaths('layouts\\\\jmLayou...', Array)
#1 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php(131): Illuminate\\View\\FileViewFinder->find('layouts\\\\jmLayou...')
#2 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/storage/framework/views/c3bf0158db836445cd08bd8673520435f1b82aa5.php(372): Illuminate\\View\\Factory->make('layouts\\\\jmLayou...', Array)
#3 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(41): include('/home/u16613500...')
#4 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/LivewireViewCompilerEngine.php(36): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/home/u16613500...', Array)
#5 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(57): Livewire\\LivewireViewCompilerEngine->evaluatePath('/home/u16613500...', Array)
#6 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(139): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get('/home/u16613500...', Array)
#7 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(122): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
#8 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(91): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
#9 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(62): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
#10 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(34): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->setContent(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#11 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(759): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->__construct(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View), 200, Array)
#12 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(731): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::toResponse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#13 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(685): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#14 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#16 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#17 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(76): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#19 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#21 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(62): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Session\\Store), Object(Closure))
#23 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#24 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#28 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(687): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#30 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(662): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(628): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#32 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(617): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(165): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#34 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#37 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#39 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#41 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(63): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#43 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#45 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#46 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#47 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#48 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(140): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#49 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(109): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#50 /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/public_html/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#51 {main}
"}
```

No entiendo cual es el problema.

Comment: intentalo asi:
en .env
`APP_URL=http://localhost` ahora en index.php 
`require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';`  y `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';` y lo que esta en `public`  va dentro de `public_html` el resto al mismo nivel.

Comment: Hola y gracias por responder, ya eso lo había intentado también, aun así lo volví a intentar como dices y nada, no funciona. En el navegador tira este error...

Comment: ErrorException
View [layouts\jmLayout] not found. (View: /home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/resources/views/index.blade.php)

Comment: que hosting es??

Comment: Hostinger.com... Hable con soporte técnico y me dicen que tienen varios proyectos en sus servidores por lo que son compatibles.

Comment: paresiera que te faltan archivos por subir. verifica que todo este arriba!

Comment: Subí todo todo lo hice tres veces por las dudas y nada sigue sin funcionar... De manera local funciona bárbaro.

Comment: que version de php esta corriendo el servidor??? en el cpanel puedes verlo y como subes tu proyecto?? solo lo que esta dentro de `public` va dentro de `public_html`  lo de mas va al mismo nivel de public_html `/home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/laravel/` de donde sale esta carpeta `laravel`? deberia ser solo `/home/u166135009/domains/jmodontologiaespecializada.com/`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111204/discussion-between-bryro-and-gian-franco-machella).